# Docker keycloak enable/disable features

Tags: docker, keycloak

I am using jboss/keycloak with docker and would like to enable/disable features of keycloak. According to keycloak's [document](https://www.keycloak.org/server/features) it can be done like this:

```
bin/kc.[sh|bat] build --features=<name>[,<name>]
```

However, if I do this within the keycloak docker container, I get the following error (same for the .bat extension):
[image]

How can I do this using a docker container?

Answer (score 0):

It's a relative path because the location depends on your install location.
You're meant to use that path and append `bin/kc.sh` to it.

In the keycloak/keycloak docker image, this path is `/opt/keycloak` ([source](https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers)).
In the bitnami image, the location is `/opt/bitnami/keycloak`.
In the jboss image, which is the one you're using, the path is `/opt/jboss/keycloak`.

Comment: I checked /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin but could not find the kc.sh file there either. Any ideas why it could be?

Comment: Is it possible that this file is under a different name than kc.sh? If so, how can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `--features="f1,f2"` by overriding docker entrypoint.

e.g. `docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.1 -c "/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build --features-disabled=dpop && /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start-dev"`